# Create possion/gaussian distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to python, and so far I have only used google for finding answers.

What I want is a small program with gaussian and possion distribution that plots histo and diagrams and provide different results.

Example: Average passing of a car at highway into the city is 3640 cars/hourly during the day. We know for instance that in the morning, there are a high peak with large traffic in the morning, and lesser and lesser during the day.

So if we want to calculate: "How many cars will enter the city between 07.00am and 09.00am and probability? Is this possible to create in python?

Would love if someone could provide an example!

Thanks.

Comment: you can do that with the random package of numpy.
poisson distribution : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.poisson.html
gaussian distribution : https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: [scipy stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) has a convenient interface to many distrubutions

Comment: Thanks for answers! I am reading about them now:) Is it too much to ask if someone could create an code sample here and provide?